# how to optimize the `button hit testing` cost in flash

Tags: flash, adobe-scout

My program is a mmorpg game using flash.
Now I found `button hit testing` cost a lot of time.
I think there is no DisplayObject to remove to speed up.
I don't know how to optimize it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a backward-compatible technique that can't be simply shut off.

Apparently, button hit testing is completely bypassed when using touch events instead of mouse events. Of course, this is not applicable if you want to target in-browser PC users..

If you're building the game for mobile devices, use touch events, like this:

```
Multitouch.mapTouchToMouse = false;
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT; 
addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onActualStageTouch);
```

A useful discussion on the Adobe forum is here: http://forums.adobe.com/message/5346701#5346701

Comment: Thanks. It's a in-browser game for pc users, so cann't use the touch method. I found a bug in my program, which add too many display objects, after fixed this bug, now the cost is acceptable .